# Which program is suitable to server mining of Feathercoin?

Tags: alternatives, server

I have web hosting virtualized Windows 2012 Server without GPU and with one core of Intel Xeon 5520.

I pay it anyway and I use about 10% CPU. I would like to use the rest for CPU mining feathercoin.

Gui miner does not work, probably because the server has no Graphic Adapter (I use remote desktop). It crash on start.

Which program should I use for such mining?